# gcc assembly vs direct to machine code

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

I recently started learning how to program, and I found this one thing curious:
Why does gcc go the extra mile of compiling the c-code to assembly and then to machine code?
Wouldn't it be just as reasonable to compile direct to machine code? I know that e.g. the MS c Compiler does this, so what's the reason for gcc for behaving like this?

Comment: `"I know that e.g. the MS c Compiler does this"` - are you sure of that?

Comment: As Jonathon insinuates, your assumptions about Microsoft's compiler are invalid. I suggest [this series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/05/29/optimizing-c-code.aspx) if you're interested in learning about the process fo compilation and linkage. Specifically, [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/12/optimizing-c-code-new-title.aspx) explains how the front-end compiler parses C++ source code into an intermediate assembly language, which is then compiled into machine language by the back-end.

Comment: I don't really see how this question is `primarily opinion-based'.  It's a technical question.

Answer (score 2):

Because for one thing, there's already the assembler who does a fairly good job at tranlating assembly to machine code -- there would be no point in gcc re-implementing that functionality. (also keep in mind that assembly still is /somewhat/ symbolic) 
On a second point, one probably doesn't /always/ want to compile straight down to machine code -- on embedded systems, there's a good chance the generated assembly undergoes a final by-hand optimization.
Last but not least, it's very helpful in debugging the compiler itself in case it misbehaves.  Nobody likes to read raw machine code.

Comment: I've worked on a compiler that generated machine code without going through an assembler. You could get an assembly listing, but it was generated separately. There was a bug where the assembly listing was correct, but the machine code was wrong. (This isn't particularly an argument for or against either approach.)

Answer (score 0):

GCC is very much unix and this is the unix way to make separate tools that build on each other rather than integrating.  You need to have an assembler and linker, the job of the assembler is to generate machine code for a target, makes no sense to repeat that.  the job of the compiler is to boil down a higher level language to a lower one.  Generating assembly language  allows for much easier debugging of the compilers output, and it lets the assembler do its job rather than repeating the task in two places.

Of course it is not only unix compilers that do this, it makes a lot of sense to do this on all platforms and has been done this way forever.  Straight to machine code is the exception rather than the rule, usually when there is a specific reason to do so.

I dont understand the fascination with this question and why it keeps getting asked over and over again.  Please search for previous answers before asking...